# Get name of mysql table in which the record exist

Tags: java, mysql, select

I have 6 tables in MySQL which are mapped like this. (Generalization/Specialization)

```
1.Expense
2.Administrative Expense
3.Vehicle Expense
4.Machine Expense
5.Salaries
6.Purchases
```

Expense is the super class and others are sub classes. The primary key "expenseId" of Expense table is referred and is the primary key of the other tables. The format of ID is "EXP0001".

I want to check whether a given ID (e.g. "EXP00010") is an admin expense or vehicle expense or likewise. What is the query to use in this case? I need to find the name of the sub-class relation which contains the given value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What problem do you have? check all tables sequentially. Or you want on DB request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the name of the table as a constant when returning rows:

```
select * from (
  select 'Expense', * from expense
  union
  select 'Administrative Expense', * from Administrative_Expense
  union
  -- etc for all tables
) all
where expenseId = ? -- or join etc
```

Comment: Thanks! got it to work. I had some problems with the "* from" where it said unexpected '*'. Just changed it a bit to select the id column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that same expense ID will not be part of more than one table, below query should work.

```
SELECT 
  a.count (*) AS admin,
  b.count (*) AS vehicle,
  c.count (*) AS machine 
FROM
  admin_expense a,
  vehicle_expense b,
  machine_expense c 
WHERE a.admin_expense_ID = 'EXP0001' 
  OR b.vehicle_expense_ID = 'EXP0001' 
  OR c.machine_expense_ID = 'EXP0001' ;
```

Regards,
Namratha

Comment: there is a syntax error in the a.count(*) part. error says unexpected '*'. expecting '(' .